# Eclipse for C/C++ Developers "Nothing to build for project"

Tags: c++, eclipse, static-libraries

I've been working with Eclipse for C/C++ (Ubuntu 16.04), and have run into a problem attempting to compile a static library of mine. This has happened with both a project with my own code and with an entirely *brand new project* (which is the weird part). The exact console output is just "Nothing to build for project NetworkingImpl". I'm not referencing any extra libraries or anything, and this is just the entirely default settings that come with a new C++ Static Library Project.

This problem has persisted through multiple eclipse restarts, computer restarts, and eclipse reinstalls, which makes me think that I accidentally modified some persistent settings file, but I have yet to find what changed (Yes, this worked at some point, but it seemed to arbitrarily stop working, I didn't change any settings that I know of).

Thanks ahead of time!

EDIT: Honestly not entirely sure what happened, but it *seems* to be working now. I think the step I took differently was I generated a whole class instead of just a header file, and for some reason that fixed the problem. I'll update this question again if the problem recurs later down the line... still confused as to *why* this was different (perhaps some weird eclipse file registering thing?), but all I know is that it's functioning now.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you posted the precise steps you took to create the project? (including what files you added)

Comment: Thank you, @Galik, that's a good idea, I'll edit that into the post now.

Comment: Okay, so it worked now, I think I took *slightly* different steps to create it (will detail in edit).

Comment: Just a header file is not compileable to a static library. You need to have a source file (`.cpp`) to produce a static library (or any binary for that matter).

Comment: That was probably it, I'm also thinking there might have been a weird issue with eclipse file tracking (this is a generally unfounded/unresearched theory, it just seemed to match what I was noticing kinda). Everything's still working fine a day later, so that's good.